# SD slot for mac mini

Tags: mac

Last year I purchased a Mac Mini from MacMall. It came without a manual or  instructions.  I'm trying to find a slot in the back to install a SanDisk card to view pictures off a trail cam. The slots will not take the card directly.  Yesterday I drove 50 miles to a Best Buy and purchased an Insignia adaptor which the salesman assured me would fit any computer made. There are only two tiny slots at the back of the mac mini and the Insignia adaptor is too large to fit into either of them. Can any one offer me some advice or must I assume the mac mini will not take any SD card.  Ron

Comment: Can you show a picture of the adapter? My guess is that they would have sold you a SD card -> USB adapter (which would plug into a USB port) or a microsd->sd card adapter (which if you had a microsd card, youd put it in the adapter then stick it in a sd card slot).

Answer (score 4):

The Mac mini, since Mid 2011, has one Secure Digital ([SDXC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Digital#SDXC)) card slot.  Prior to that, the Mid 2010 models have one Secure Digital ([SD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Digital#SD)) card slot and prior to 2010 the Mac mini has no card slot.

Back side of Mac mini (Late 2014):

[image]

If the flash memory card is a micro card, then to use the SD/SDXC card slot, you need an SD card Adapter as shown in the example image below.

[image]

If you do not want to use the SD card slot then you'll need a USB SD Card Reader. As an example, the [Insignia™ - USB 2.0 SD/MMC Memory Card Reader - Black](http://www.bestbuy.com/site/insignia-usb-2-0-sd-mmc-memory-card-reader-black/3602009.p?id=1219092580719&skuId=3602009), which is compatible with, SD, SDHC, SDXC, microSD, microSDHC, microSDXC, MMC and MMC+ memory cards on PC and Mac, shown in the image below.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for responding to my question. You have the right "insignia" adaptor above.  how the back of my 2015 Mac Mini does not look anything
like the picture posted above.  Where the SDXC card slot is shown on the above picture, my Mac Mini has the power cord. Once again, I can not find a slot that the insignia adaptor will slide into.

Comment: If you have an Insignia device as shown in my answer, then you have a USB Memory Card Reader **not** an adapter as the adapter is as shown in my answer of the SanDisk Adapter. If what you have is the Insignia USB Memory Card Reader, then that gets inserted in a USB slot not the SD/SDXC card slot! As to your comment "_my 2015 Mac Mini does not look anything like the picture posted above_", first, there is no 2015 model of the Mac mini, the latest Mac mini is the Late 2014 model and the picture in my answer is of it. So without seeing a picture of what you have it hard to say what you do have!